# Understanding MDX 'ALL'?

Tags: sql, mdx, olap

I'm new to MDX coming from the world of SQL and I am trying to understand the concept of 'ALL'. I am understanding that 'ALL' is a single member, creating a cube with low granularity as far as that dimension is concerned. Is this correct?

What are some examples of SQL that can help me reason about this concept? Of course, SQL uses tables not cubes, but I'm sure there are some similarities which can help me make the connection? Let me try to create an example.

Let's say I have a table with such a schema representing a cube with 3 dimensions:

```
myTable (dim1_attribute1,dim1_attribute2, dim2_attribute1,dim2_attribute2,dim2_attribute3,
dim3_attribute1,dim3_attribute2,dim3_attribute3)
```

What kind of SQL would give me an aggregate with 'ALL' granularity on dim3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'ALL' means that basically you are taking into account all members of that dimension - you are not slicing cube with some particular member of that dimension. In SQL query equivalent would be to omit dim3 from the where clause altogether, so you are not filtering your resulting aggregation with some particular value from dim3 but you are taking all rows into account.

Comment: Please note there may be multiple levels that cannot just be added (budget, actual, etc). I a cube you can model these as top members without an all member above them. In SQL you'd need to think of this cae yourslef.

Comment: @vldmrrdjcc so to be clear, when looking to use the ALL member for dim3, e.g. rolling up over the ALL member for dim3, it's like totally removing the 3x dim3 attributes mentioned above from the SQL query SELECT/GROUP BY to achieve the coarsest granularity?

Comment: @gjvdkamp could you provide more details on this case?

Comment: sometimes members 'roll up' into their parent, for instance the sales figures for different branches roll up into the total 'all' for the total company. In that case omitting the dim3 in a where/ groupby would give you the total for all branches and all is well.But you can also have members where does not make sense to add them up, like the example budget, actual etc. Adding those together would just result in duplicated numbers. In that case no where/grouby would lead to meaningless results.